# Postfix のドキュメントで表現される「クライアント」の定義

Tags: postfix

Postfix で不正利用対策のために、「 smtpd_client_message_rate_limit 」を設定しようと、ドキュメントを見ますと、「client」という表現がでてきます。

このときの「client」というのは、メール送信時に使用するアカウント名（ID)なのでしょうか？
それとも、接続元IPアドレスを指しているのでしょうか？

どちらを意味しているのかで、設定しようとする値が全く別ものになるので、どちらで解釈すればよいのでしょうか。

ご存知の方がおりましたら、ご教示ください。

環境： Postfix 2.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMTPの文脈で言う時の「クライアント」はTCP/IPのクライアントと同義、つまり接続元のIPアドレスのことと考えればいいと思います。